xrandr --off: reboots system instead of disabling display
I'm trying to disable the display of my laptop with the following cli:
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off

The display immediately disables but then the laptop REBOOTS sometime after 0~600 seconds.
I've tried some debug, but no success so far:

External display works fine.
ie: properly disabled by xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off and no system reboot.
journalctl is posted bellow, but I could not decipher it.
HandleLidSwitch=ignore and others makes no difference.

Any idea what might be happening?

Additional Info

Notebook: Gateway NE56R
CPU: Intel Pentium 2020M
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12.8

Debug: External Display
I've plugged an external HDMI display and run:
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --off

Everything seems to work fine.
Ie: the display immediately was disabled and the laptop did not rebooted.
Debug: journalctl
Most of the time I see nothing unusual at journalctl. However, sometimes I get the following log after the xrandr:
root@debian:~# journalctl --boot=-1 | tail -n 25
Dec 27 00:26:03 debian systemd[1]: user-108.slice: Consumed 1.497s CPU time.
Dec 27 00:26:13 debian systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' unit='xdg-desktop-portal.service' requested by ':1.26' (uid=0 pid=1015 comm="xscreensaver-settings")
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service...
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Documents' unit='xdg-document-portal.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=0 pid=1018 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal")
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Starting xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore' unit='xdg-permission-store.service' requested by ':1.28' (uid=0 pid=1022 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal")
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Starting xdg-permission-store.service - sandboxed app permission store...
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore'
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Started xdg-permission-store.service - sandboxed app permission store.
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents'
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Started xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service.
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian xdg-document-portal[1022]: Ignoring invalid max threads value 4294967295 > max (100000).
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk' unit='xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=0 pid=1018 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal")
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Starting xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk'
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Started xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation).
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian rtkit-daemon[657]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian rtkit-daemon[657]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian rtkit-daemon[657]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian xdg-desktop-portal[1018]: pw.conf: can't load config client.conf: No such file or directory
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian xdg-desktop-portal[1018]: pw.conf: can't load default config client.conf: No such file or directory
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian xdg-desktop-por[1018]: Failed connect to PipeWire: Couldn't create PipeWire context
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian dbus-daemon[771]: [session uid=0 pid=771] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
Dec 27 00:26:21 debian systemd[751]: Started xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service.

Unfortunately, IDK whether this log is an issue or not.
Debug: HandleLidSwitch and others
I've also modified /etc/systemd/logind.conf and changed the HandleLidSwitch line to HandleLidSwitch=ignore. Similar to several other lines:
HandlePowerKey=ignore
HandlePowerKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleRebootKey=ignore
HandleRebootKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleSuspendKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleHibernateKey=ignore
HandleHibernateKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

Unfortunately, nothing happened (ie: system still reboots after xrandr).

That sounds like a serious driver or hardware bug. Can you do this, i.e., cause the reboot, then on the booted machine run journalctl -b -1 -k to get the kernel logs of when the device crashed, and see whether there is something at the end about what went wrong?

If you want to, journalctl -b -1 -k | curl -F 'file=@-' https://0x0.st will upload the full log to a server, and give you a link that you can share with us. (you will need curl, but chances are that's already installed on your system. If not, sudo apt install curl.)

@MarcusMüller > "cause the reboot, then on the booted machine run journalctl -b -1 -k" Nope, nothing unusual. However, journalctl -b -1 sometimes give some strange log. I've just updated the OP with this and other debug info. Let me know what you think.

@MarcusMüller > "give you a link that you can share with us." At the moment I'm more familiar with pastebin: https://pastebin.com/aTbWBu6D .  Let me know what you think.
